# Modifying a variable from parent scope when inside a local function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to accomplish something like the following:

```
def counter():
    _n = 0
    def _increase():
        _n += 1
        return _n
    return _increase
```

The above example should behave like this:

```
>>> c = counter()
>>> c()
1
>>> c()
2
>>> c()
3
```

However, when trying to reproduce this, I get the following error:

```
>>> c = counter()
>>> c()

UnboundLocalError: local variable '_n' referenced before assignment
```

---

It looks like it's trying to find the variable in the local scope, so I changed my code to the following:

```
def counter():
    _n = 0
    def _increase():
        global _n
        _n += 1
        return _n
    return _increase
```

It appears that it's able to locate it just fine now, but apparently it's uninitialized, even though I'm executing `_n = 0` before even declaring the function.

```
>>> c = counter()
>>> c()

NameError: name '_n' is not defined
```

---

Clearly I'm doing something wrong and I'm not aware of a specific Python behavior in this case.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword.  It allows you access variables defined in a surrounding scope, but not the global scope.

```
def counter():
    _n = 0
    def _increase():
        nonlocal _n
        _n += 1
        return _n
    return _increase
```

Now it should work as you intended.

```
>>> c = counter()
>>> c()
1
>>> c()
2
>>> c()
3
```

Comment: Amazing! I was not aware of this keyword at all! Is this something new on Python 3.x? Never seen it on 2.x code. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Yes, it was added in v3.

Comment: As I understand it, `nonlocal` searches enclosing scopes (nearest first) till it finds the named variable (taking the first it finds). It requires the variable to be defined at some point, but won't use a global variable. (If this understanding is wrong, please add a note here...)